# Is it possible to send data (ex: 'hello') from a python webserver to a python script running on the same device?

Tags: python

So I've scoured through Google and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a simple python webserver running, and I'm using fttt and ngrok to communicate to the server, but can't seem to get the server and script to communicate.

Is there a way to get a python script to listen to the server for incoming data and is there a way to send data from the server to the script?

Comment: Open a socket using the server's address and port. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I forgot about that! I've even used this in different projects before, not dealing with webservers exactly but still. I feel like such a dummy hahaha.

Comment: You could also use named pipes. If the server spawns the sub-script you could use stdin/stdout via [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). There's also [memory mapped files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html), regular files, signals, etc.